# The sum $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots)$ does not exist.

Tags: sequences-and-series

What are the argument(s) that I can use proving that

$$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots)$$

does not exist.

The question was:

Find a arrangement of $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ for which the new sum is not exist(even not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$)

Comment: This is a confusing definition of the word "sum." You have two infinite series.

Comment: both term diverges to $\infty$

Comment: The rules for operator precedence might be invoked.  In particular the "expression" inside the parentheses needs to be evaluated first.  However that "expression" appears to be a divergent infinite series, so one can argue its evaluation is not possible.

Comment: I will edit to add some more info.

Comment: What you have is not a valid rearrangement.

Comment: For the **original** question you were asked, take positive terms until the sum is $\ge 1$, then negative terms until the sum is $\le 0$, then positive terms until the sum is $\ge 1$, then negatives until sum is $\le 0$, and so on. The first few are $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+ \cdots $.

Answer (score 4):

One should be careful in dealting with infinity series.

The sum 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac 1 n
$$
is well known as an alternating series, which converges(to $\ln 2$).

However, the series
$$
\left(1+\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 +\ldots \right)-\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 +\ldots 
\right)
$$
does not exist if not specitied. The series
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {2k}\right)
$$
exists and is $\ln 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint for your problem

$$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$$

diverges. So does
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots$$

Lets denote the partial sums by

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} \,;\, T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k} \,.$$

Now pick $n_1$ so that

$$S_{n_{1}} >1 \,.$$

Pick $m_1$ so that $T_{m_1}> S_{n_1}$.

Pick inductively $n_i, m_i$ so that

$$S_{n_{i}} >1+T_{n_{i-1}} \,,$$
$$T_{m_i}> S_{n_1} \,.$$

Then

$$S_{n_1}-T_{n_1}+(S_{n_2}-S_{n_1})-(T_{n_2}-T_{n_1})+(S_{n_3}-S_{n_2})-(T_{n_3}-T_{n_2})+...$$

oscillates above 1 and below 0. More exactly, for all $k$,

$$S_{n_1}-T_{n_1}+(S_{n_2}-S_{n_1})-(T_{n_2}-T_{n_1})+(S_{n_3}-S_{n_2})-(T_{n_3}-T_{n_2})+...+(S_{n_k}-S_{n_{k-1}})>1\,,$$
$$S_{n_1}-T_{n_1}+(S_{n_2}-S_{n_1})-(T_{n_2}-T_{n_1})+(S_{n_3}-S_{n_2})-(T_{n_3}-T_{n_2})+...+(S_{n_k}-S_{n_{k-1}})-(T_{n_k}-T_{n_{k-1}})<0\,,$$

**P.S.** The idea of the proof is simple to understand: add enough positive terms to go over 1. Then subtract enough negative terms to go under 0. Then add enough of the next positive terms to go over 1. Then subtract enough of the next negative terms to go under 0. Repeat.

You can do this process because of the above series go to $\infty$.

Comment: Sir there is some latex error .

Answer (score 0):

This does exist. The series is $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i+1} a_i$$ where $a_i=\frac{1}{i}$ which is an alternating seres. Since the limit of $a_i$ as $i$ tends to infinity is zero and $a_i$ is monotonically decreasing, the series converges.

Although, you should be a bit careful writing things this way. The two series should really be merged so it doesn't look like you're trying to do arithmetic with infinities.

Comment: The limit of terms $a_i$ being zero is necessary, but not sufficient, for the _series_ to converge.

Comment: true, the $a_i$ should also be monotonically decreasing which I've added in

Comment: Thes series you mention is not equal to the OP's $\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{2k}$ which, indeed, does not define a real number, not even $\pm \infty$.

Comment: technically no in the way it is written. Hence the last paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is of much help for the OP, but note that I did not downvote as everything you say is true.

Comment: ahhh, looking back I believe the OP has edited the question since I orignially answered.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 positive terms, 4 negative terms, 8 positive, 16 negative, and so on.
The resulting series of summations will oscillate between positive and negative values,
never approaching any limit.