# evaluate the sum of an alternating harmonic series with a fixed limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions

Hi I stumbled across an alternating harmonic sum with a fixed limit on an practice exam and I've no idea how to calculate this sum.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{1}^{100}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now the point of the exercise is to make an approximation to this sum and compare it to
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \tag{2}.$$
So naturally I tried to convert $(1)$ into an integral so I could make an approximation based on that, however I found it hard to integrate $$\frac{\cos(x)}{x}. $$ 
Then I tried to make use of Leibniz criterion but that got me nowhere. Since I guess there is a way to make an approximation of $(1)$. I would gladly accept any tip on how to solve this!
Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots)$ does not exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407828/the-sum-1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-frac12-frac14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from par's answer, you can use the expansion of the harmonic numbers for large values and, in such a case, you find that, for even values of $n$, $$\begin{equation}
S=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 m}+\frac{1}{16 m^2}-\frac{1}{128
   m^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^5\right)
\end{equation}$$ Using this expansion, for $m=50$, you will find $$S\approx \log (2)-\frac{3980001}{800000000} =0.68817217930994530942$$ while the exact value would be $$S=\frac{47979622564155786918478609039662898122617}{697203752297124771645338089353123035
   56800} \approx 0.68817217931019520324$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easier way to prove the answer is log(2).

$$\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right) + C = \int \dfrac{1}{1-x} dx =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int x^{k-1} dx  = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{k}}{k} $$

Assuming $C=0$ (which can be shown choosing x=0), at $x=-1$ we get

$$\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{k}$$

For your sum, a well known estimate of an alternating series $\sum(-1)^nb_n$ where $\{b_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ is given by

$$|S-S_N| \le b_{N+1}$$

Since $S = \ln(2)$, we have

$$\left|\ln(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{100}(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{100+1}$$

i.e.

$$\ln(2)-\dfrac{1}{101} \le \sum_{n=1}^{100}(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n} \le \ln(2)+\dfrac{1}{101}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to think about it...

For $n$ even,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k} & =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k+1}\\
 & =\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\frac{1}{2k+2}\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}+\log4\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}-H_{\frac{n}{2}+1}\right)+\log2
\end{align*}
where $H_{j}$ is the $j$-th harmonic number. As $n\rightarrow\infty,$
$H_{\frac{n}{2}}-H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rightarrow0$, and hence we are
left with $\log2$.

Comment: Ehm I don't know how that would help me solve the approximation of my integral from 1 -> 100, am I missing something? :O

Comment: Sir, what is meaning of $H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$

Comment: @MohanSharma: $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.