# Calculate $\sum_{k=51}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a sum to calculate:

$$\sum_{k=51}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} $$

And I have no idea about how to proceed. What kind of techniques are available to calculate this?

Comment: The parentheses around the $-1$ are of utter importance; else the series will be divergent.

Comment: What do you know about $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

Comment: @graydad I know that I can use a taylor expansion to get it to be -ln(1+1)

Comment: Right! Well, almost... There shouldn't be a negative out front of the $\ln$ should there?

Comment: @graydad true it shouldn't. But how does that help me? I can state it as $ln(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{50} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ but how to I calculate that sum?

Comment: You nailed it. Do you have access to a computer where you can calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{50} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$? Because there is no quick way to calculate that by hand. I guarantee that is an ugly number.

Comment: yes, but shouldn't it be possible to do it without a computer? The result itself is not as interesting as learning...

Comment: It is definitely possible to solve by hand. It's just that you'll have to find a common denominator for the fifty fractions that you have to add together. I recommend using a denominator of $50$ factorial. I think the equation $$\sum_{k=51}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} = \ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{50} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} $$ is exactly the answer you are looking for. I should clarify about when I said "possible to solve by hand." You do NOT want to do this by hand. It will take way too long and is just an exercise in adding fractions.

Comment: And how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots)$ does not exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407828/the-sum-1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-frac12-frac14)

Answer (score 7):

Start with the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\log(1+x)$:

$$\log(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$$

and take $x=1$ (that this is allowed follows from [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)) to find

$$\log(2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

Now split the sum into two parts:

$$\log 2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{50}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} + \sum_{k=51}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

The first term can be calculated on a computer (there is no known (useful) formula you can use so a calculation is needed here)

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{50}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} = \frac{2117413358024481287753}{3099044504245996706400} \approx 0.68324716$$

Thus giving us

$$\sum_{k=51}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} = \log 2 - \frac{2117413358024481287753}{3099044504245996706400} \approx 0.00990002$$

If you are only looking for an approximate value: The terms in the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ alternates being positive and negative and the absolute value of the terms decreases with $k$. [This means that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) the sum you are after satsify:

$$\left|\sum_{k=51}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\right| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{50}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\right| < \left|\frac{(-1)^{51-1}}{51}\right| = \frac{1}{51}$$

so the sum you are after is less than $0.02$ (which is indeed the case).

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks!