# Estimate the sum of alternating harmonic series between $7/12$ and $47/60$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

How can I prove that: 
$$\frac{7}{12} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} < \frac{47}{60}$$

? I don't even know how to start solving this...

Comment: your sum has the value $\ln(2)$

Comment: how did you compute that?

Comment: This sum is also known as the "alternating harmonic series" which converges to $\ln(2)$

Comment: see also here http://www.efunda.com/math/exp_log/series_exp.cfm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots)$ does not exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407828/the-sum-1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-frac12-frac14)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that the series converges using [Leibniz Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation).

Next, denote by $S_N$ the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$.  Then, we must have $$S_{2N}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}<S_{2N+1}$$

Finally, we see that $\sum_{n=1}^4 \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\frac{7}{12}$ and inasmuch as the next term is positive, the value of the series must exceed $7/12$.  Similarly, we see that $\sum_{n=1}^5 \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\frac{47}{60}$ and inasmuch as the next term is negative, the value of the series must be less than $47/60$.

Comment: Is it also true that $S_{2N} < \sum_{n=1}^{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} < S_{2N+1}$ ?

Comment: Shanon, I don't understand the meaning of the notation on the upper limit.  Is $k$ any natural number?  If so, then it cannot be true.

Comment: You wrote that after $n=5$ the next term is negative. But the next term after that is positive so why does the value of the series must be less than $47/60$ ?

Comment: Term $6$ is $\frac{(-1)^{6-1}}{6}=-1/6<0$

Comment: And $7$ is $1/7 > 0$

Comment: Yes.  But $S_{5}=\sum_{n=1}^5\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=47/60$

Answer (score 3):

If $s_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k}$ then $\left(s_{2n-1}\right)_{n=1,2,\dots}$
is monotonically decreasing and $\left(s_{2n}\right)_{n=1,2,\dots}$
is monotonically increasing.

This with $s_{2n}<s_{2n-1}$.

So if you can find some $n$ with $\frac{7}{12}<s_{2n}<s_{2n-1}<\frac{47}{60}$
then you are ready.

Comment: I did not understand the last sentence... What do you mean I can findsome $n$ within that range? I understood that $S_{2n} < S_{2n-1}$ , can you elaborate more?

Comment: $s_{2n+2}<s_{2n+1}<s_{2n-1}<\frac{47}{60}$ and so on. Likewise $s_{2n+1}>s_{2n+2}>s_{2n}>\frac7{12}$ and so on. So the inequality stays valid for larger $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint your sum is integration of $\int (1+x)^{-1}$ after integration put $x=1$ . So series converges to $\ln(2)$

Comment: Since $x = 1$ lies at the boundary of the interval of convergence, there are some subtleties (involving Abel's Theorem) in giving a careful proof that the given series converges to $\log 2$.  But this can certainly be done, so let's assume it: then how will you show that $\frac{7}{12} < \log 2 < \frac{47}{60}$?  The easiest way to do this is to use the Alternating Series Test  / Leibniz's Test as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The manipulation
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n x^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x+1} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{2-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)\,2^{n+1}}$$
gives a substantial convergence boost, and summation by parts gives a second boost:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1) 2^{n+1}} = 1-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+1}}\tag{1} $$
By evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{4}\frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}$ and $1-\sum_{n=0}^{3}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+1}}$ we get the improved inequality:

> $$ \color{red}{\frac{661}{960}}\leq \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\leq\color{red}{\frac{667}{960}}.\tag{2}$$